# Numpy consider a subclass of list as not a array-like

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I make numpy consider a subclass of `list` as not a array-like?

For example:

```py
import numpy as np
class A(list):
    pass

values = [A((1,2)), A((3,4))]
array = np.array(values, dtype=np.object_)
```

Will create an array of `int`, not array of `A` even though `dtype=object_` is set.

Also, I need an array of objects because the shape must be kept. For example: Array of `class Car` with shape `(1,3,1)` will become a tensor of `(1,3,1,5,3)` where a single car is represented as a tensor of shape `(5,3)`.

Comment: The answer is, "don't do that".  When you are a subclass of list, you promise to behave like a list.  Numpy knows how to handle lists.  You can use encapsulation instead of inheritance.

Comment: @TimRoberts By "Use encapsulation", do you mean that `class A` should have the `list` variable?

Comment: It's not clear even with the explanation why you need to do this. If a car is represented as a tensor of shape `(5, 3)`, why not represent it as an array? It's not clear why you need the subclass.

Comment: "Also, I need an array of objects because the shape must be kept. " I'm not sure I follow you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make an object dtype array, you can fill it with list like objects:

```
In [150]: arr = np.empty(3, object)

In [151]: arr
Out[151]: array([None, None, None], dtype=object)

In [152]: arr[:] = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6]]

In [153]: arr
Out[153]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5]), list([6])], dtype=object)
```

The lists can all be the same size:

```
In [154]: arr[:] = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

In [155]: arr
Out[155]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 6]), list([7, 8, 9])], dtype=object)
```

or an array, or your custom class:

```
In [159]: arr[:] = [np.arange(3)*i for i in range(1,4)];arr
Out[159]: array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 2, 4]), array([0, 3, 6])], dtype=object)
```

What I'm showing is that you can make a object dtype array containing various things - but don't use `np.array(...)`.  That tries too hard to make multidimensional numeric array.  It's hard to bypass that effort.